# Cannot read property '0' of undefined Angular 2/4 Unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript

I created a unit testing for a service file like this

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { OrderGroupingService } from './order-grouping.service';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { BaseRequestOptions, Jsonp, Http, HttpModule, JsonpModule, 
ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { CommonError } from 'app/services/helper/commonerror';
import { tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { orderGrouping } from 'app/entity/orderGrouping';

fdescribe('OrderGroupingService', () => {
let service: OrderGroupingService;
let backend: MockBackend;
let orderGrouping: orderGrouping

beforeEach(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [OrderGroupingService, MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions, CommonError,
    {
      provide: Jsonp,
      useFactory: (backend, options) => new Jsonp(backend, options),
      deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
    },
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: (backend, options) => new Http(backend, options),
      deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
    }],
  imports: [HttpModule, JsonpModule]
});
// Get the MockBackend
backend = TestBed.get(MockBackend);
// Returns a service with the MockBackend so we can test with dummy responses
service = TestBed.get(OrderGroupingService);
});

it('Should Be Created Order Grouping Service', 
inject([OrderGroupingService], (service: OrderGroupingService) => {
expect(service).toBeTruthy();
}));

it('Add Order Groups And Returns Success Message', fakeAsync(() => {

let response = {
  "results": [
    {
      "message": "Saved successfully."
    }]
};

this.orderGrouping = {
  partyRoleId: 313,
  description: "sampleName"
}

// When the request subscribes for results on a connection, return a fake response
backend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
  connection.mockRespond(new Response(<ResponseOptions>{
    body: JSON.stringify(response)
  }));
});

tick();

// Perform a request and make sure we get the response we expect
service.addOrderGroup(this.orderGrouping).subscribe(res => {
  debugger;
  expect(res.results[0].message).toBe("Saved successfully.");
}, );

}));

 });
```

Here my first test case is passed. But the second one always fails and it says 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined'. My second test case is 'Add Order Groups And Returns Success Message'. Is there any idea what is wrong? database working correctly.

Comment: trigger the `fixture.detectChanges()`

Comment: And... what's the code of the service? Also, why are you using the deprecated HttpService instead of HttpClient?

Comment: I'm working with Angular 4